# Creating a WriterT[F, W, A] from a Writer[W, A]

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

In Scalaz, is there an easy way to convert an instance of `Writer[W, A]` (which is an alias for `WriterT[Id, W, A])` to `WriterT[F, W, A]`?

I'm looking for something similar to the `optionT` function combined with `point`, but for writers instead:

E.g.

```
// Similar situation, but using OptionT
val opt:  Option[String] = Some("log")
val optT: OptionT[IO, String] = optionT(opt.point[IO])

// Case in hand, using WriterT
val w:  Writer[String, Unit] = "log".tell
val wt: WriterT[IO, String, Unit] = ???

// Similar scenario
val w:  Writer[String, Int] = 3.set("log")
val wt: WriterT[IO, String, Int] = ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some monadic types have `lift` methods that help with this kind of operation:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect.IO

val stateIO: StateT[IO, Int, Unit] = put(10).lift[IO]
```

`Writer` doesn't, but you can use the `Hoist` instance for `WriterT` to accomplish the same thing:

```
type StringWriter[F[_], A] = WriterT[F, String, A]

def fromId[F[_]: Applicative]: Id ~> F = new (Id ~> F) {
  def apply[A](a: A) = a.point[F]
}

val w:  Writer[String, Unit] = "log".tell
val wt: WriterT[IO, String, Unit] = Hoist[StringWriter].hoist(fromId[IO]).apply(w)
```

This isn't terribly convenient, but that's something you have to get used to when working with monad transformers.